# Patching SSRS on Always On Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I have SSRS 2016 installed on Always On Availability Groups.  I have patched my secondary servers with SQL Server patches.  When I failover SSRS will not connect to the databases, it has an error

> The version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '175'. The expected version is '173'.

How can I get this new server to connect?  What is the proper way to upgrade SSRS with 2016 AG's?

Comment: Read this article. This explains your case.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32360.sspr-troubleshooting-the-version-of-the-report-server-database-is-either-in-a-format-that-is-not-valid-or-it-cannot-be-read.aspx